# set write permissions on a file for one person everybody else just read

Tags: windows, file-permissions

i have a windows server 2003. What permission do i have to set to allow one person to have read write access while everybody else has just read

Comment: the only thing i am stuck with is on everybody do i deny access or just uncheck allow

Comment: Don't use deny unless you have a very rare case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're talking about a file share, since you don't specify.

On the share ACL, set "Authenticated Users" to Full Control.

Make a group called `<ShareName>_RW`

Add the user that should write to this group.

Break permission inheritance for that share.

Make it so that the NTFS ACL on the share says:

```
Administrators - Full Control

<ShareName>_RW - Modify

Users - Read
```

The user that you just put in that group won't have access until he/she logs off and back on.